# Looking for an old scifi novel - Scientists on an atoll, Antigravity test, murders every day

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I'm looking for a book I read as a young teenager, having pilfered it from my dad's "sci-fi shelves" - which probably dates it as 50s-70s given the other books he had.

The premise was a number of scientists living on an atoll, trying to make a working antigravity drive. One by one they are murdered.

Spoiler to help with identification:

> The "whodunit" is that a parasitic alien, I think from a crashed spacecraft, has been taking over their minds one by one and causing the murders. It's probably better than that if you read the book, and I seem to remember we end up understanding why the alien has done it, though I can't remember why.

There is a very vivid description of antigravity including a car on a stretch rubber road stretched over rollers - that will make sense if you know the book!

Tried to google all the obvious keywords with no success! I'll be very pleased if someone can prove I didn't dream the whole thing.

Comment: I've been looking for ages and found nothing. There are plenty of books about parasitic aliens, there are plenty of books on Antigravity, and there are a LOT of books involving murder. But all 3? Doesn't seem to exist. Can't even find any reference to the car on the rubber road. Your best bet is probably to head on over to your dad's and scour his sci-fi shelves until you find it. Assuming it's there to be found, of course XD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is "[Count-down](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13437073-count-down)" by Charles Eric Maine. Doesn't rate well on GoodReads but I seem to remember enjoying it. Just need to track a copy down now, but at least I know what it's called.

> *KALUIKI… an island-name destined to become a household word, along
>   with the names of eight courageous people—Farrant, Strang, Hoevler,
>   Earl, MacClennon, Youd and the two women, Kay Kinley and Hilde
>   Bartok—if “the project” could be brought off successfully. It took
>   three days to warm the reactor up to the critical point of Zero Hour.
>   Meanwhile, some strange insanity had been let loose on the
>   security-bound island. How long would it take to kill eight people?
>   How long before some of them panicked or shut themselves uselessly in
>   the safety of a locked room?*

I found it buried in someone's essay on how antigravity is presented in Scifi.

Comment: The serialization in *New Worlds* is available at the Internet Archive; see issues [[81](https://archive.org/details/New_Worlds_081v27_1959-03)], [[82](https://archive.org/details/New_Worlds_082v28_1959-04)], [[83](https://archive.org/details/New_Worlds_083v28_1959-05)].

Comment: There are several murders. The villain turns out to be a time traveller from the future who is trying to sabotage the anti-gravity project.              The central character does quite a bit of driving, but I can't find anything about a rubber road It's a rough hill track on which bulldozers have smoothed out the worst of the jaggedness

Comment: The "rubber road" was used by one of the characters as an allegory for the fictional antigravity drive: "Launching a rocket is like driving a car up a hill ...lets have a road made of rubber and lets have a gadget that can grip the road from underneath... so that you get a dip in the slope... under the wheels of the car... the car tries to roll forward into the hollow of the dip... you box clever and slide the dip up the hill."

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you are remembering Hal Clement's [Needle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needle_(novel)).

Points of similarity:

- Takes place in ocean / islands (maybe an atoll, can't remember).
- Parasitic alien.
- Time frame (published 1950).

Dis-similarities:

- I don't remember anything about antigravity or rubber roads, but it's
  been a long time.
- No murders (per FuzzyBoots).

Comment: Also no murders as best I can tel.

Comment: thank you - will take a look and see - but based on the WP review, think it's probably not the one - IIRC the setting was much more in an engineering / science project. And of course, there were murder-death-kills! :)